Pyspark sub library update
In azure devops, requirements.txt contain pyspark 3.5.3 but while scanning using jfrog it shows vulnerabilities inside pyspark package. Vulnerabilities mainly in jackson mapper like maven repo json libraries. Also jfrog mentioning the fixed versions. How to update maven repo library in this scenario

add more details like what you are expecting and your current setup for doing repro.

Provide the detailed error/warning message returned by jfrog scan? And have you contacted the publisher of pyspark package to mention vulnerabilities?

I have tried the below:
updating the Jackson dependency for a runtime session of PySpark using spark.jars.packages.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Update Jackson") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.2") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2") \
    .getOrCreate()

Results:
Loaded Jackson version:
2.15.2

Next you can update Devops pipeline using Updated Maven dependencies:
echo "Overriding Maven dependencies for Spark"
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dcom.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.2"

Updated Jackson library ( version 2.15.2) and confirming the change using spark.sparkContext._jvm.

Vai_007 Can you check if the solution helped you?
